# jsonencode add an empty row, why?

Tags: php, json, android-studio

I've done a long search before posting, none of solutions work for me.
I'm creating an Android application, using JSON and PHP;

PHP

```
/**
*
LOT OF USELESS THING
*
*/
//Attributing values of $OUTPUT

$q=mysql_query($query);

if (!$q) 
   die(mysql_error()); // You'll be notified if there's any syntax error in your query.  

$OUTPUT = array(array());           
if ($q && @mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node

    while($e=@mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        if (!empty($e['title'])){
        $u = Array();
        $u['id'] = mb_convert_encoding($e['id'], 'UTF-8');
        $u['title'] = mb_convert_encoding($e['title'], 'UTF-8');
        $u['location_search_text'] =  mb_convert_encoding($e['location_search_text'], 'UTF-8');
        $OUTPUT[] = $u;}
        //echo "<br>************<br>";*/

            //$OUTPUT[] = $e;
    }
}
print(json_encode($OUTPUT));
```

Now, this is the output of json:

```
[[],{"id":"796","title":"ANSEJ ORAN \/Agence de Soutien \u00e0 l'Emploi des Jeunes d'Oran","locat ...etc
```

If you see, there's a []; an empty array, which of course causes me problem in Java, when parsing data with

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Occuring me a JSONExcpetion:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `$OUTPUT = array(array());` - this create empty array inside

But `$OUTPUT = array();`

Comment: I'm in love with your answer :) Thanks !